# How to zoom to a specific country with OSMDroid?

Tags: android, osmdroid

Assume the following situation:
The User chooses a country from a list. After clicking on a country, the map should zoom to the selected country.

How can I achieve the zoomToCountry in OSMDroid if I only know the country name from the list?

In the PHP API "GoogleMaps v3" there is a solution like

```
function findAddress(address) {
        var geocoder = null;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        if (!address) 
        var address=document.getElementById("countryselect").value;
        if ((address != '') && geocoder) {
          geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
               if (results && results[0] && results[0].geometry && results[0].geometry.viewport) 
                    map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
              } else {
                alert("No results found");
              }
            } else {
              alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
          });
        }
    }
```

Is there any similar in OSMDroid or the OSMBonuspack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP solution is a call to geocoding service with the country name, to get country bounding box.

You can do something similar using Nominatim service. So OSMBonusPack GeocoderNominatim should be usable.

Roughly that (without error handling, AsyncTask and so on):

```
GeocoderNominatim coder = new GeocoderNominatim(ctx);
List<Address> results = coder.getFromLocationName(countryName, 1);
Address address = results.get(0);
Bundle extras = address.getExtras();
BoundingBoxE6 bb = extras.getParcelable("boundingbox");
```

Then:

```
mapView.zoomToBoundingBox(bb);
```

As simple as PHP/GoogleMaps solution, isn't it?

Comment: Th error is in line: `GeocoderNominatim coder = new GeocoderNominatim(context);` **Source not found.** with a button **Edit Source Lookup Path...** sorry, I am new to android. Thx for your help

Comment: Is working after adding gson-2.3.1,jar to the Build Path! (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1)

Comment: Need for GSON was mentioned in the installation guide. Do you mean that you had no gson at all, or that you had to replace gson-2.2.4.jar with gson-2.3.1.jar?

Comment: I didn't had any GSON.! Probably missed this point in the installation guide ;)